# Update a document I don't know the doc ID cloud functions

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to access a document to update it but ***there is only one document in the collection***, I don't know the id of that document, how can I access it knowing that there w

```
return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).collection('score').doc().update({
   points: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(10),
})
```

This code doesn't work, I get the error: No document to update.

I understand this is because calling the .doc() method just generates a random id. So how can I access the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only update a document in Firestore if you know the exact path to that document. If you don't know the path yet, you'll have to read the document(s) to determine that.

If you want to update all documents in the collection, this means that you can just call `get()` on the collection to get all documents. Even when there's only a single document, you still have to update all one of them.

The code looks something like this:

```
let collectionRef = admin.firestore().collection('users');
collectionRef.get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    doc.update({
      points: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(10),
    })
  });
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
```

Also see the documentation for [getting all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).

---

If you're using this in Cloud Function or another environment that can't leave promises unhandled, you'll need to bubble up the results:

```
let collectionRef = admin.firestore().collection('users');
return collectionRef.get().then(snapshot => {
  return Promise.all(snapshot.documents.map(doc => {
    return doc.update({
      points: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(10),
    })
  }));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the ID of a document, you can't just `get()` it individually.  You will have to perform a query on the collection it's in.  If you perform a query, you will either have to know something about one of the fields inside it, and [filter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) for it (getting potentially many matching documents), or you will have to simply get every document in the collection by providing no filter at all on the collection.

There are no workarounds to this.  You really have to do something to remember that document ID, or know something about its fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
 admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).collection('score').get().then(snapshot => {

 const docId = snapshot[0].id;
 return 
    admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).collection('score').doc(docId).update({
    points: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(10),
    })
 })
```

this is only for one doc in the collection. snapshot[0].data().id return 1st doc ID.